# How could i Print a block of text in PHP

Tags: php

I have a HTML file which contains a table. Using the "file_get_content()" i am reading the file then. when i print the content of the HTML file the "" tags getting printed in the new dynamic page .But i want to print the table only in the webpage. How could i do this

Comment: Do you mean "Print" as in "put the file contents into the output"?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean printing like with a browser.

But PHP runs on the server, so printing is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you mean "Put into the output" by "print" (your question's somewhat ambiguous here), echo the result of the file_get_contents call.

Or just use readfile.

If you just want a particular part of a HTML file (a table contained in the markup) then use the domdocument extension to extract the element from the document and output that instead.

If you mean "send to the printer", then you can't do that from PHP.